# Finding Text in Email Body With InStr

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I want emails with bodies that contains the text in the active cell.

I get

> "Class does not support Automation or does not support expected
>   interface."

I am using the same line of code for the subject which is working.

Part of my code:

```
    For Each obj_item In folder.Items
        If obj_item.Class = olMail Then

            Set obj_mail = obj_item

            ' If InStr(1, obj_mail.Subject, active_cell_value, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then

            If InStr(1, obj_mail.Body, active_cell_value, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then

                Application.StatusBar = row_number & " - " & folder.FolderPath

                On Error Resume Next
                Cells(row_number, 1) = obj_mail.EntryID
                Cells(row_number, 2) = folder.FolderPath
                Cells(row_number, 3) = obj_mail.ReceivedTime
                Cells(row_number, 4) = obj_mail.Sender
                Cells(row_number, 5) = obj_mail.Subject
                Cells(row_number, 6) = obj_mail.To
                On Error GoTo 0

                row_number = row_number + 1
                msgs_found_counter = msgs_found_counter + 1
            End If
        End If
    Next obj_item
```

Edited: moved `On Error Resume Next` before `For Each obj_item In folder.Items` to wrap almost everything

```
    On Error Resume Next
    For Each obj_item In folder.Items
        If obj_item.Class = olMail And obj_item.EntryID <> "" Then

            Set obj_mail = obj_item

            ' If InStr(1, obj_mail.Subject, active_cell_value, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then

            If InStr(1, obj_mail.Body, active_cell_value, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then

                Application.StatusBar = row_number & " - " & folder.FolderPath

                Cells(row_number, 1) = obj_mail.EntryID
                Cells(row_number, 2) = folder.FolderPath
                Cells(row_number, 3) = obj_mail.ReceivedTime
                Cells(row_number, 4) = obj_mail.Sender
                Cells(row_number, 5) = obj_mail.Subject
                Cells(row_number, 6) = obj_mail.To

                row_number = row_number + 1
                msgs_found_counter = msgs_found_counter + 1
            End If

        End If
    Next obj_item
    On Error GoTo 0
```

RESULT:

[image: Screenshot of the result]

Comment: Did you try `obj_mail.HTMLBody`?

Comment: @braX, I tried and it returns the same error. Let me know if you want me to post the whole code.

Comment: This is a very strange error.  According to Microsoft it means: "Either the class you specified in the GetObject or CreateObject function call has not exposed a programmability interface, or you changed a project from .dll to .exe, or vice versa."  I assume `obj_Mail` is an `Outlook.MailItem` and `active_cell_value` is a `String`.  I would use Watch to examine `obj_Mail` and `active_cell_value` to make sure there are what you think they are.

Comment: Another thought.  In `For Each obj_item In folder.Items`, you are using `folder` as a variable name. But `Folder` is a data type and `folder` is either of type `Folder` or `MAPIFolder`.  It is possible the interpreter is confused.  Try changing `folder` to `MyFolder` or `FolderCrnt` or some other name that does not match a data type.

Comment: Does this happen on the very first item in the folder? Or only after you process a few items?

Comment: @Dmitry and everyone, I moved "On Error Resume Next" before "For Each obj_item In folder.Items" to wrap almost everything with it and Dmitry is right, the error might have been thrown by the first item. I included a screenshot in my post, please see it.

Comment: @Tony, thank you. I will check the data types and research about "Watch"

Comment: @TonyDallimore please see my comment above.

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko please see my comment above

Answer (score 0):

Putting `On Error Resume Next` and `On Error GoTo 0` around an entire block is rarely (never?) a good idea during development or investigation.  They just mean that you have no idea which statement is causing an error and limits your ability to identify and fix the error.

Judging from the result image, the first item does not have an `EntryID`, `ReceivedTime`, `Recipients` or `Sender`.  My first reaction was that it was a draft and these properties had not been assigned yet.  I did not find that a convincing answer because, in my experience, properties that have not been initialised have valid values such as "" or 0.  I then saw “Recall” in the subject.  I am retired and am no longer a corporate user, but I remember emails being recalled.  I cannot investigate without access to this functionality.  However, according to the documentation I can find, the item will be a `ReportItem` rather than a `MailItem`.  A `ReportItem` had an `EntryId` but does not have `ReceivedTime`, `Recipients` or `Sender`.

My suggestion is:

Delete the `On Error Resume Next` and `On Error GoTo 0`.

Add something like:

```
If TypeOf obj_mail Is MailItem Then
    ' Output MailItem properties
ElseIf TypeOf obj_mail Is ReportItem Then
    ' Output ReportItem properties
Else
  ' Report unexpected item
End If
```

If you still get an error, execution will stop at the statement giving the error.  Hover over the statement, to discover which object or property is the cause of the error.  Use Watch to examine that object and discover what is not as you expect.  This should allow you to add code that avoids the error; perhaps it’s another type of item.

If you cannot avoid the error, try something like this:

```
Dim ErrNum As Long
Dim ErrDesc As String
   : : : 
On Error Resume Next
Statement giving the error
ErrNum = Err.Number
ErrDesc = Err.Description
On Error GoTo 0 
If ErrNum <> 0 Then
  Code to handle, report or ignore error
Else
  Code to handle normal situation
End If
```

Note: in my opinion this is the correct way to use `On Error Resume Next` and `On Error GoTo 0`.  Place them around a single statement.  Save `Err.Number` in a variable because `On Error GoTo 0` clears `Err.Number`.  Test `ErrNum` and take appropriate action.